# Task Scheduler - Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Tags: c#, console, scheduled-tasks

I have a strange issue.  I have built a C# console app that is loading PowerPoint PIA to parse the PowerPoint into slides, converts slides into images and compares the images with one another.

The problem is that when I run the exe using the console, it runs correctly having no problems, but when I set it in task scheduler and run from there, it throws an error "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program".

Any idea is welcome.

Thanx,
Ilija

Comment: THe followign actually fixed the problem

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64

Comment: You actually answered your own post and thanked yourself?...

Answer (score 1):

In case the solution link dies at some point. The instructions that worked for me are:

・Windows 2008 Server x64

Please make this folder.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

・Windows 2008 Server x86

Please make this folder.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop